# Next.js can't fetch inside API route

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next to manage a flow in which a customer subscribes to a product via stripe, then with a web-hook, it triggers another API call taking the info from stripe to generate a new enrolment key for my other service.

This is all working fine, however when I go to post the info from stripe to the third party API, anything inside the fetch just doesn't run.

Everything works fine for me locally when posting the function through the front end, but I want it to be all handled on the backend automatically. The customer will never know this next app exists.

Not sure if its even possible to fetch to another API within an API route itself...

**`pages/api/hooks.js`**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url';
const getRawBody = require('raw-body');

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.LIVE_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
    apiVersion: process.env.STRIPE_API_VERSION,
});

// Disable next.js body parsing (stripe needs the raw body to validate the event)
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

let _customer = {};
let _subscription = {};

//
// This posts the stripe data to another api route
//

const initEnrollment = (origin) => {
    fetch(`${origin}/api/enrollment/create`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            subscription: _subscription?.id,
            currency: _subscription?.currency,
            customer: _subscription?.customer,
            email: _customer?.email,
            name: _customer?.name,
            address: _customer?.address,
            cycle: _subscription?.plan?.interval,
            amount: _subscription?.plan?.amount,
        }),
    })
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('The king has returned    ', res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};

const hooks = async (req, res) => {
    const headers = req.headers;
    const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);

    try {
        const rawBody = await getRawBody(req);

        const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            rawBody,
            headers['stripe-signature'],
            process.env.LIVE_STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
        );

        // Get the object from stripeEvent
        const object = stripeEvent.data.object;

        // Handle the event
        switch (stripeEvent.type) {
            case 'customer.created':
                const customerCreated = stripeEvent.data.object;
                _customer = customerCreated;
                break;
            case 'customer.subscription.created':
                const customerSubscriptionCreated = stripeEvent.data.object;
                _subscription = customerSubscriptionCreated;
                initEnrollment(origin);
                break;
            default:
            // console.log(`Unhandled event type ${stripeEvent.type}`);
        }

        // Send success response
        res.send({ status: 'success' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('stripe webhook error', error);

        // Send error response
        res.send({ status: 'error', code: error.code, message: error.message });
    }
};

export default hooks;
```

I've tried using axios and node-fetch but both have the same result.

I've also tried on version 13 and 12 with the same result :(

It seems that next doesn't like it when you try to fetch / post to another API route whilst your inside one. usually this makes sense, however its not even working for an external API.

All my env vars are set up too.